# Is it possible to disable virtual table behavior of Natable

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable

In my case i am using more number of columns and rows in my nattable. In all those columns i am using customized cell painters varies for each column as per my need.

no the problem is,

Whenever i do  horizontal scrolling, scrolling speed and the columns moving speed aren't the same. there is delay. if i remove the all the cell painters the scrolling is in perfect in sync with the columns moving speed.

i checked in the code cell painters execute every time i move the scroll. i think this is because of the virtual table behavior of the nattable.

is there any way to disable that behavior.

if that is possible what would be consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. And disabling the virtual nature would make the issue even worse, as in this case it would try to render everything, also things that are not visible.

Of course the painters are executed on scrolling. This is how nattable works. It paints!

The issue you describe is typically caused by time intense label calculation or painter code. I don't know what you mean with "customized cell painters" and how much delay you notice. But the virtual nature is definitely not the cause.

And to answer the question, remove the ViewportLayer from the body and there is no virtual behavior.

Comment: Hello Sir, I am using a custom cellpainter which extends nattable Text painter. Delay i am facing is after i move the horizontal bar 2 to 2.5 seconds delay is there. it feels like while moving scroll bar, columns are does not moving , it is more like jumping.

Comment: Typically an issue of the painter that is doing some time consuming operation on rendering.